# Water running from off shower head

Tags: plumbing

I have a shower only setup with an handheld shower head. I find that it sometimes drains water from the shower head long after the water has been turned off. It doesn't happen all the time but just randomly. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is that following a warm shower as the metal water pipes cool after shutting off the valve, the tubing contracts more than the water in it, and some water is forced out the shower head.

If you want to prevent this, let the shower head hang down for a time after you turn off the water so most of the water in the flexible connecting tube drains out.

Comment: As a test of the explanation in my answer I nearly filled a tin can with boiling water outside at 53 F. As the can and water are cooling the level in the can is dropping not rising as I expected!? Maybe evaporation? I'll try it again but cover the can.

Comment: Level drops with can covered. I filled up an aluminum water bottle with warm water and let it sit outside. the level dropped slightly as it cooled. Temporarily stumped. I have experienced this delayed dribbling with fixed shower heads. I am currently using a removable shower handle with flexible hose but in a tub shower with a divert valve. After a shower I switch the divert valve to the neutral (horizontal) position to let the water above the valve drain out the tub spigot. I am not finding any delayed dribbling.